# possible to set indentation to same line as above in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

If I am at a line and  I want to set it to be as the same indentation as the line above me, isthat possible without a plugin? how would I do that?

so if I have

```
line above
         line im on now,i want to indent to same place as above
```

how would  I do this in vim?

Answer (score 0):

`:set autoindent`. See [help on autoindent](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoindent%27).

Comment: that is not the same, i want to move the current line to the same ident as above line

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>i :exec 'normal k0v^hyj'<Bar>exec 'normal ^h0v^h'<Bar>exec 'normal P'<CR>
```

Explaining:

This map copy the indentation of the line above:

- `k` move to previous line
- `0` move to first character
- `v` visual selection move
- `^` move to first non-blank
- `h` move one character to left
- `y` yank visual selection

Then:

- `j` go to next line

Any map with a move error with abort so we need to split what can fail, this is: visual select the indentation of line (which can be 0). for that are the `exec` and `<Bar>`

- `^` move to first non blank
- `h` move one character to left (will fail if there's no indentation)
- `0` move to first character
- `v` start visual selection move
- `^` move to first nonblank
- `h` move one character to left

With or without selection:

- `P` replace selection with text yanked

Notes:

- **1**: Translate this into a function will avoid slowness on visual selection
- **2**: Contemplate the case were above line has no indentation is not solved